# How do I set meshCollider.cookingOptions to MeshColliderCookingOptions.Everything in code?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm procedurally generating some meshes for a project, and I need to add colliders to them. The meshes are generating fine, but after setting the shared mesh in the mesh collider, I need to be able to set the cookingOptions to Everything. In the inspector, I can do this fine and the colliders work correctly. Since I am generating these at runtime, I can't really do this after making a build. How do I go about doing this?

Works Correctly:
[image: With Everything selected, collider works correctly.]

Does not Work Correctly:
[image: Without Everything selected, collider doesn't work correctly.]

Comment: Can you describe the symptoms of "not working correctly"? This might help us identify what setting is missing under the hood.

Comment: Sorry this is a bit late. By not working properly, I meant that the colliders were not being generated correctly. There would be a collider component on the object, but no collision mesh in the scene.  I've resolved this since (it was during a game jam and I honestly forgot I had asked this question) by setting the convex flag on, then off again, which appeared to generate the collision mesh. Certainly not efficient (very low framerate) but did what I needed.

Comment: Sounds like you should post that solution as an answer then. Glad you solved it!